# How to test Devise in a Controller RSpec, error: undefined method `assign' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x0000010597f4b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, rspec2

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `assign' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x0000010597f4b8>
```

When attempting to test per [the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29).

Here's is what I have:

**user_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "devise/sessions/new.html.erb" do
  let(:user) do
    stub_model(User).as_new_record
  end

  before do
    assign(:user, user)
    # Devise provides resource and resource_name helpers and
    # mappings so stub them here.
    @view.stub(:resource).and_return(user)
    @view.stub(:resource_name).and_return('user')
    @view.stub(:devise_mapping).and_return(Devise.mappings[:user])
  end

  it "renders a form to sign the user in" do
    render
    rendered.should have_selector("form",
                                  :method => "post",
                                  :action => user_session_path
                                  ) do |form|
      form.should have_selector("input", :type => "submit")
    end
  end
end
```

Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rspec has changed a bit, it's now using `assigns`.

[Doc here](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/views.html).

Comment: Thanks, would love to get your feedback on my follow-up question. I'm really lost on how to get started and right tests for devise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223549/howto-write-tests-for-devise-omniauth-in-my-rails-3-app

Comment: When changing to assigns it still errors with: Failure/Error: assigns(:user, user)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: So I changed it to: assigns[:user] = user which causes it to now error on undefined local variable or method `render' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x000001051c5f38>

Comment: You use deprecated methods, browse the doc here: http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html